# custom setup has been not installed in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, onestepcheckout

I have custom module which is **OneStepCheckout**, in that I have added 2 fields to existing table. But it's not installed in `core_resource` and `tables` also fields are not installed.

my code is:

**magento\app\etc\modules\Easylife_OnestepCheckout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_OnestepCheckout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Easylife_OnestepCheckout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\OnestepCheckout\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_OnestepCheckout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Easylife_OnestepCheckout>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <onestepcheckout>
                <class>Easylife_OnestepCheckout_Model</class>
            </onestepcheckout>
            <onestepcheckout_adminhtml>
                <class>Easylife_OnestepCheckout_Adminhtml_Model</class>
            </onestepcheckout_adminhtml>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <links>Easylife_OnestepCheckout_Block_Links</links>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
            <onestepcheckout>
                <class>Easylife_OnestepCheckout_Block</class>
            </onestepcheckout>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <url>Easylife_OnestepCheckout_Helper_Url</url>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
            <onestepcheckout>
                <class>Easylife_OnestepCheckout_Helper</class>
            </onestepcheckout>
        </helpers>
    </global>    
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\OnestepCheckout\sql\onestepcheckout_setup\install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php  

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'sales_flat_order',
    'giftwrap',
    array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'grid' => false,
        'required' => false,
    )
);

$installer->addAttribute(
    'sales_flat_order',
    'giftwrap_price',
    array(
        'type' => 'decimal',
        'grid' => false,
        'required' => false,
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Can I know where I went wrong?

thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the system/exception log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config xml is missing resource definition in `<global>` node

```
   <resources>
        <onestepcheckout_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Easylife_OnestepCheckout</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </onestepcheckout_setup>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Ahhh..I was 35 seconds late.

Comment: The funny thing is that our answers are almost identical. Even text)))

Comment: That's because is the right answer. I will delete mine, since is the same thing and you typed faster .:)

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, I wrote this in `config.xml` file but not installed in `core_resource` as well `tables`. can i know reason behind error?

Comment: @Marius, I wrote this in `config.xml` file but not installed in `core_resource` as well `tables`. can i know reason behind error?

Comment: @MagentoNav clear the cache.

Comment: @Marius, No, not installed, Is this required to Create `Model,Resource` & `Collection` file?.

Comment: @MagentoNav I don't think so

Comment: If you just adding attributes in your upgrade script then you do not need to create `Model,Resource & Collection`.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, then why it's not installed in `core_resource`? and tables? please suggest me?

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi, setup is installed but error is came see my thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/cant-retrieve-entity-config-sales-sales-flat-order