# Can't retrieve entity config: sales/sales_flat_order

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, onestepcheckout

I am trying to add column existing table `sales_flat_order` but it's returning an error

```
Can't retrieve entity config: sales/sales_flat_order
```

my code is:

```
<?php
 //@var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/sales_flat_order')}` ADD `giftwrap` SMALLINT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/sales_flat_order')}` ADD `giftwrap_price` DECIMAIL(12,5) NULL;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

can I know where I went wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sales_flat_order` is the full name of the table and you should use alias in `$installer->getTable()`

If you take a look in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\etc\config.xml` there is table definition

```
<sales_resource>
    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource</class>
    <deprecatedNode>sales_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
    <entities>
       ....
       <order>
           <table>sales_flat_order</table>
       </order>
       ...
    </entities>
</sales_resource>
```

So `$installer->getTable()` should get parameter `module_alias/table_alias`.

In your case

`module_alias = sales`

`table_alias  = order`

```
$installer->getTable('sales/order')
```

As a result it will return table name `sales_flat_order`.